# Nextion Display not updating data from Arduino

Tags: arduino, potentiometer, display

I am using an Arduino Mega to display the readings of 4 pots on a Nextion Display as well as store it in an SD Card with the time stamp. I keep getting

> recvRetCommandFinished err

on the serial monitor and the display does not update with time.

I have attached my code below:

```
#include "Nextion.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS1307 rtc;
char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

// Declare your Nextion objects - Example (page id = 0, component id = 1, component name = "b0") 
NexText tDate = NexText(0, 1, "tDate"); 
NexText tPot1 = NexText(0, 6, "tPot1");
NexText tPot2 = NexText(0,7, "tPot2");
NexText tPot3 = NexText(0, 8, "tPot3");
NexText tPot4 = NexText(0, 9, "tPot4");

File myFile;

void setup(void) {    
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }
  if (! rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
    // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
    // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
    // January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
    //rtc.adjust(DateTime(2016, 11, 19, 19, 45, 0));   // <----------------------SET TIME AND DATE: YYYY,MM,DD,HH,MM,SS
  }
  delay(100);
    
  // You might need to change NexConfig.h file in your ITEADLIB_Arduino_Nextion folder
  // Set the baudrate which is for debug and communicate with Nextion screen
  nexInit();
  SPI.begin();
  int pot1 = 0;
  int pot2 = 0;
  int pot3 = 0;
  int pot4 = 0;

  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin(53)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
  // so you have to close this one before opening another.
}

void loop(void) {   
  myFile = SD.open("testpot1.csv", FILE_WRITE);
  // if the file opened okay, write to it:
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.print("Writing to testpot1.txt...");
    while(1) {
      DateTime now = rtc.now();
      myFile = SD.open("testpot1.csv ", FILE_WRITE);
      int pot1 = analogRead(A0);
      int pot2 = analogRead(A1);
      int pot3 = analogRead(A2);
      int pot4 = analogRead(A3);

      myFile.print(now.hour());
      myFile.print(":");
      myFile.print(now.minute());
      myFile.print(",");
    
      myFile.println(pot1);
      myFile.println(",");
      tPot1.setText(pot1);

      myFile.println(pot2);
      myFile.println(",");
      tPot2.setText(pot2);

      myFile.println(pot3);
      myFile.println(",");
      tPot3.setText(pot3);

      myFile.println(pot4);
      myFile.println(",");
      tPot4.setText(pot4);

      Serial.print(pot1);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(pot2);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(pot3);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(pot4);
      Serial.print(",");
   
      delay(2000);
      myFile.close();
    }
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
}
```

[image: Image of the serial Monitor]

How do I get the pot values on my display? Any help or tips would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the text components to the number components and I was able to get the display the pot values on my screen.